# How can explode elements randomly?

Tags: php

**This is my code:**

```
function get_random(){
    $filter_word     = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';
    $array = explode(',', $filter_word);
    $randomKeys = array_rand($array, 2);
    $str = '';
    foreach($randomKeys as $key){
        $str = $array[$key];
    }

    return $str;
}
```

The problem that if I used `array_rand` i must know the number of elements to can add the number in `array_rand` and I can't know something like this (it's a data stored into the database) so if the elements are less than two it gives me an error:

> Warning: array_rand(): Second argument has to be between 1 and the number of elements in the array

Is there a better way to make this?

Comment: `shuffle($array)` then `array_pop($array)` for each random element you want.

Comment: `function get_random($arr) { return $arr[array_rand($arr)]; }`

Comment: @AlexHowansky  can you give me an example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `count()` before using `array_rand`-

```
function get_random(){
    $filter_word     = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';
    $array = explode(',', $filter_word);
    $str = '';
    if(count($array)>1){
       $randomKeys = array_rand($array, 2);

       foreach($randomKeys as $key){
           $str = $array[$key];
       }
    }
    else{
            $str = $filter_word;
     }
    return $str;
  }
```

Comment: The same thing if it's only one element it's give me a error: Warning: array_rand(): Second argument has to be between 1 and the number of elements in the array

Comment: Error changing to: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: that means you have single data, may be you could try limiting divide by 2, see the updated answer

Comment: Yes, i know this and this is my problem I want if there is only one element then get and not print an error.

Comment: @John I have made your answer completely, make a try

Comment: Thank you but there's another error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '('

Comment: which line you having this problem??

Comment: $str = array[0]; and i think thats because my php is 5

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like this:

```
$randCount = rand(1, count($array));
$randomKeys = array_rand($array, $randCount);
```